# Empy list on return

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have this in my qweb report

```xml
 <span t-esc="formatLang(get_routing_data(o)[-1]['total'] , digits=3)"/>
```

it works ok, but sometimes it returns an empty list and then i get error index tuple out of range. how can i avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the return value of the call to `get_routing_data` into a variable and make check the value using `t-if` conditions before use it, like:

```
<t t-set="routing_data" t-value="get_routing_data(o)"/>
<span t-if="routing_data and len(routing_data) > 0 and routing_data[-1].get('total', False)" t-esc="formatLang(routing_data[-1]['total'], digits=3)"/>
```